# access last changed revision

Tags: svn

I had a question about accessing the last changed rev. I'm using svn info to get the information and store it in a file. The file stores info like revision, url, last changed revision. I access these values in build.xml by creating a property. While I can get url and revision using property.url and property.revision respectively, how do i access last changed rev?

Thanks people,

Shriram

Answer (score 0):

Use [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) to retrieve those details.

Comment: yes. im using svn info to get the details. i wanna access the last changed revision.
for instances, if you wanna access/store revision, u use a property and access it like property.revision.
similarly, how do i access last changed revision??

Answer (score 0):

You may find using [svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#info) is much cleaner than using exec to call the CLI svn client.  You can automatically store the last changed rev in `svn.info.lastrev`

Comment: I have no idea about svnant but I figured out a way to do it. Appreciate it.